# Reallocating array causes "Aborted" error

Tags: c, arrays, vector, struct

I wrote the following struct for a vector:

```
typedef struct Vector_ Vector;

struct Vector_
{
    int dim;
    double* vector;
};
```

And I wrote a function to initialise a new instance of that struct:

```
Vector* newVector(int length){
    int i = 0;
    Vector* vec = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    assert(vec != NULL);
    assert(length > 0);


    vec->dim = length;
    vec->vector = malloc((length+1)*sizeof(double));
    assert(vec->vector != NULL);
    for(i=0;i<=length+1;i++) vec->vector[i] = 0;
    return vec;
}
```

This all works, but then I wrote a function to reallocate memory and change the length of the vector like this:

```
Vector* setVectorLength(Vector* vec, int length)
{
    assert(vec->dim > 0);
    int i = 0;
    if(length > vec->dim)
    {
        vec->vector = realloc(vec->vector,(length+1)*sizeof(double));
        assert(vec->vector != NULL);
        for(i = vec->dim+1;i<=length;i++)
        {
            vec->vector[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        vec->vector = realloc(vec->vector,length+1 * sizeof(double));
    }
    vec->dim = length;
    return vec;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    Vector* newvec = newVector(5);
    setVectorLength(newvec,8);
}
```

For some reason, the line in the setVectorLength function where I reallocate the memory of the vector array causes the program to abort. If I comment out that section, everything works. Interestingly, I am able to write entries to the array even without reallocating it to a sufficiently high length, so for example, if I only initialise the vector struct and give it the length 5, then I can write values into the 7th or 8th spot of the vec->vector array, even though I never allocated that much memory to it. Any hints?

Comment: Learn to count to n in C. If your array size is `n`, you need to allocate exactly `n` elenents, not `n+1`, not `n-1`, not any other number. Easy! If you have `n` elements, the proper for loop to enumerate them all is `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)`. Note not `n+1` and not `<=`.

Comment: This `length+1 * sizeof(double)` is the same as `length+ (1*sizeof(double))` is the same as `length + sizeof(double)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And btw. I do know how to count, but my assignment literally asked me to make this struct of length+1, so there is not a single thing I can do about it.

Comment: @user3121023 You were right, it is indeed outside of bound thank you!

Comment: Why do you call `realloc()` in the case of `!(length > vec->dim)` as well?

Comment: OT: All those `int`s should be `size_t`s.

Comment: @alk thanks for the suggestions. The reason why I reallocate in the else-case is because I want to shorten the memory allocated and let realloc cut off the last entries. Isn't that how to do it?

Comment: @M3xr fyi, this is actually a reasonable use for a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Comment: You could ask your prof/TA *why* +1 is needed.